# Resuming interrupted SVN checkout... again

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, resume, svn-checkout

First of all, I know that this question has been asked many times, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031845/svn-resuming-aborted-checkout). However, the accepted answers there do not seem to work in my case.

```
> svn --version
svn, version 1.7.6 (r1370777)

> svn co https://netmf.svn.codeplex.com/svn netmf
```

After it starts adding files (~ after 1 min), interrupt the checkout (ctrl-c). It won't run through anyways in one try.

```
svn: E200015: Caught signal

> cd netmf

> svn cleanup 

> svn up
Updating '.':
At revision 25495.

> svn st
!      bin
```

So, it sees that the folders are incomplete. However, it thinks that it is already at the newest revision and does not resume the download.

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Note that although I intentionally interrupt the checkout in this test case, the same problem occurs automatically later on, as the repository is very large and the checkout is interrupted due to other circumstances at a later time.

Same issue with Tortoise GUI and on another machine.

**Update**

Same issue with svn on OS X 10.8.2

**Update**

There seems to be another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801950/codeplex-svn-how-good-is-svn-bridge) that seems to share similar issues as I have. Maybe it's a server problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [svn resuming aborted checkout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031845/svn-resuming-aborted-checkout)

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031845/svn-resuming-aborted-checkout

Answer (score 4):

First Try SVN clean UP then SVN update.. it will work..

Comment: Could you add some detail to your answer? Why are you convinced this will work? Raw "do this" answers are not very useful.

Comment: If there is no problem with your repository server. and the checkout has been interrupted by network problem, then svn cleanup and svn update works for resuming, because i was facing the similar problem and i tried it and it worked!!!..

Comment: Thanks  Billal BEGUERADJ

Answer (score 0):

I see two things that you can try here:

```
svn update --force
```

or, if it's not working

```
svn revert . -R
```

Comment: Well... sort of. It seems that the behavior depends on _when_ you stop the checkout.

Comment: OK, I'll try again with not stopping it and running it until it breaks.

Comment: Another idea I didn't tested yet is to get the file list through `svn ls -R` and call `svn update` for each file...

Comment: Still does not work.  svn -ls -R gives `svn: E175002: PROPFIND of '/svn': could not connect to server (https://netmf.svn.codeplex.com)`

Answer (score 0):

Do an SVN Switch again to the repository

```
cd netmf
svn switch https://netmf.svn.codeplex.com/svn
```

Comment: After 10 minutes of waiting:

`svn: E175002: REPORT of '/svn/!svn/bc/25496': Could not read status line: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
 (https://netmf.svn.codeplex.com)`

Answer (score -4):

You could try downloading the repository using git-svn.

```
git svn clone -s -r1 https://netmf.svn.codeplex.com/svn
```

Then you either copy the checkout on top of your svn checkout or start working with git. 
The `-rN` switch determines the number of last revision it should check out (in the example above only the latest revision is downloaded from the server). 
If this still doesn't work you will probably have to checkout the repository with all the incremental changes:

```
git svn clone -s https://netmf.svn.codeplex.com/svn
```

Comment: I would prefer a pure SVN solution. Nevertheless: did this really work for you?

Comment: RA layer request failed: PROPFIND of '/svn': could not connect to server (https://netmf.svn.codeplex.com) at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 1343

I used: `git svn clone -s -r2 https://netmf.svn.codeplex.com/svn`